# typescript does not compile files in directory

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a small typescript project and created the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
    "./typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Two files app.ts and hero.ts contain typescript code.

`tsc -p .` does not trigger any compilation.

`tsc hero.ts app.ts` triggers the compilation.

I cannot tell why `tsc -p .` does not work.

## Context

I installed typescript using npm.

% which tsc
...path_to_project/node_modules/.bin/tsc

The dependencies section of my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "backbone": "^1.3.3",
    "backbone.localstorage": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^2.3.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your files aren't being compiled because you've set the `files` property in your .tsconfig as

```
 "files": [
    "./typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
```

By using the `files` property you're telling the compiler to compile only these files. Either remove the `files` property altogether or add your app.ts and hero.ts files

If the `files` property is excluded then the compiler defaults to including all typescript files.

Furthermore:

> When input files are specified on the command line, tsconfig.json
>   files are ignored.

This is why when you run `tsc hero.ts app.ts`, your files are compiled.

Comment: I don't have `tsconfig.files` property in my config. It doesn't compile as well

Comment: @Green - my answer was to this question in particular and in this case the answer was correct. No need for a down vote because it hasn't answered your specific question.